# Radian integrated terminal in VScode does not open in current file directory despite "terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-r

In my Vscode setting, I have set the variable `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}"` so that any new integrated terminal opens in the current file directory and not the parent project directory - which is the default setting in VScode. This works for all my terminals (CMD, BASH,POWERSHELL).

However, Radian always opens an integrated terminal with the project folder directory (parent directory). Is there a setting to override this behavior or a work around so that my R terminal (radian) is always opened in the directory of the current file?